# Generic view with additional parameters (if possible) or context processors to pass extra info to the template?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a generic `ListView` that returns a list of objects.

All was good before I decided to print how many time passed since creation time (not just *when* the object was created) for every object.

Then I need a piece of code to count it and I need to pass the results to the template.
But now I can't use a generic view.

I thought about `context processors`, but `context processors` take only `request` as a parameter and I need to give it also the `id` of an object to count the time delta.

So, is there any way to make it using generic views or context processors or I have to code a custom view? Or is there a better way?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks everyone for detailed answers, it will greatly help me in the future.

I learned that the mentioned task can be solved using [timesince built-in template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince). Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `get_context_data` and add more data to the context dictionary:

```
class MyView(ListView):
    # ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['mydata'] = ...
        return context
```

You can then use `mydata` in the template.

You can also access `context['object_list']` which contains the list of objects that will be displayed in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Simeon's answer is the obvious one if you need to add more stuff in the context for a specific ListView, but you can also use custom templatetags or filters if you need something that doesn't directly depend on the view itself. In you case a simple filter computing the delta from any date or datetime might be the ticket. Extra bonus: you can reuse it on any date in any template without having to change anything in the views...